# How to "finalize" a new row

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

So I've been running into some trouble tonight with my c# windows forms application. Is it possible to insert a new row to a datagridview when the currently selected new row is still on its default values? Or, if I want to change the values programmatically, how can I emulate the user editing the textbox in order to finalize the row?

To clarify, when a row is a new row (and shows up as true with the `isNewRow` property), I cannot figure out how to change out of the `isNewRow = true` state to generate a new empty row below.

I've tried `dataGridView.EndEdit()`, `dataGridView.CurrentRow.DataGridView.EndEdit()`, `bindingSource.EndEdit()`, and none of these have really done the trick. (also, using `dataGridView.BeginEdit()` puts the text box into `editmode`, which isn't handy, because I can't seem to edit the cell programmatically after that)

Ideally, I would like to be able to continue to hit enter on new rows, while changing their values with a custom control, or not, and have a new row appear underneath.

Does anyone have any solutions to this?

Comment: better show the code you've tried ..

Comment: Is this data grid view bound to any background data object?

Comment: Have you tried Validate?  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.iscurrentrowdirty.aspx  "To commit row changes programmatically, call the form's Validate method. If your data source is a BindingSource, you can also call BindingSource.EndEdit."  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.containercontrol.validate.aspx

Comment: Yes, I am using a binding source.

Using the validate method only seems to clear the cell, and BindingSource.EndEdit does not do anything

Comment: I'd also like to add that the issue is only when adding a new row. With the same code, I can currently make changes to old rows just fine. The problem seems to be that I can't commit new rows to the binding source.

Comment: Why don't you add the new row to your data source? It should appear in your grid. I mean why exactly do you need to go from another end?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Okay so I figured how to make this work.
When modifying the values using my custom control, I had to use

```
bindingSource.EndEdit();
dataGridView.NotifyCurrentCellDirty(true);
dataGridView.EndEdit();
dataGridView.NotifyCurrentCellDirty(false);
```

So whenever changes are made to the new row, it forces the row to be committed and adds a new blank row space to the end of the datagridview.

I did not have to use Validate(), however.

Comment: I found myself that I only needed the `dataGridView.NotifyCurrentCellDirty(true); dataGridView.EndEdit();`. Anything less left the row in a cancelable new state. I put those lines in a `BeginInvoke()` call in the handler for `BindingSource.AddingNew` (because in my case I was populating the default values for the new thing by setting `AddingNewEventArgs.NewObject`).

Comment: Actually, I’m wrong, all those lines are necessary. Otherwise `DataGridView` gets into invalid state and crashes the process. Wat.

Comment: It seems that correct order should be:

`dataGridView.EndEdit();
dataGridView.NotifyCurrentCellDirty(true);
bindingSource.EndEdit();
dataGridView.NotifyCurrentCellDirty(false);`