# Manually adding a new row to DataGridView does not immediately update the bound DataTable

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0, datagridview, datatable

I have a c# windows form app written in .net-4.0

I have a datagridview (`dgvItems`) which I programmatically bind to a dataset and datatable at the end of an import function.

I have an import button that imports data from a selected excel file into a table called `_dtItemAdjustList`, once the data has been imported I bind that table to my grid. The code I use to bind the grid is:

```
dgvItems.DataSource = _dsQtyAdjust;
dgvItems.DataMember = "Item Adjust List";
dgvItems.Refresh();
```

Everything works fine so far, if I edit the imported data in the datagridview, it updates the bound table `_dtItemAdjustList` after each cell is edited.

My issue comes in when I try to manually add a row to my datagridview, it doesn't immediately add that new row to the bound datatable.

Example: I put a break point at the end of my `dgvItems_CellValueChanged` event and added a `_dtItemAdjustList.Rows.Count` watch and here is what happens.

After the data is imported and I edit one of the existing imported lines the watch shows the correct row count, lets say **5**.

Now I click the last * row, and type something into my item# column and hit tab, the break point fires but my row count still only shows **5**, I fill out a few more cells in the new row but each time I leave a cell and my CellValueChanged event fires and the row count remains at **5**.

Next I add a second manual row, now immediately after I tab out of the first cell I filled out for this second new row, my row counter goes to **6**, but technically at this point I've added **2** manual rows to my imported **5**, so the counter should read **7**

This repeats, basically each new manually added row to the datagridview isn't added to the bound datatable until either **a)** another row is added or **b)** I go back and re-edit a cell on an existing row.

Edit
Forgot to mention I tried binding my DataGridView two ways:

```
DataSource = _dsQtyAdjust //dataset Name
DataMember = "Item Adjust List" // Table Name in the dataset

DataSource = _dtItemAdjustList
```

It made no difference as far as my new row behaviour goes.

Comment: Assuming Winforms (which you did not specify as a tag), I find that the datamember name you use is not the table name! I would bind using this format DatagridviewName.DataSource=DataTableName.

Comment: @EmmadKareem sorry, forgot to clarify this in my question. I tried binding the DataGridView both ways, it didn't make a difference. I have edited my question with this information.

Comment: So is the name _dtItemAdjustList.TableName=="Item Adjust List" ?

Comment: @EmmadKareem Yes. I did find a solution that seems to work perfectly. I used a BindingSource instead of directly binding my DataGridView to my DataTable. I posted it as the Answer. Thank you for taking the time to reply, it's much appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

Ok after a lot of trial and error and online searching I found a solution that seems to work.

Instead of binding my DataGridView directly to my DataTable, I created a BindingSource, bound the BindingSource to my DataTable, then bound my DataGridView to the BindingSource and finally in my `dgvItems_CellValueChanged` event I used a combination of `EndEdit()` and `NotifyCurrentCellDirty(true/false)` to make it work.

Code sample:

```
public partial class frmQuantityAdjustment : Form
{
    // In my forms partial class I created a new public BindingSource
    public BindingSource bsItemAdjust = new BindingSource();
}

private void frmQuantityAdjustment_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // In my form_Load event I bound the BindingSource to my DataTable
    // and then the DataGridView to the BindingSource
    bsItemAdjust.DataSource = _dtItemAdjustList;
    dgvItems.DataSource = bsItemAdjust;
    dgvItems.Refresh();
}

private void dgvItems_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    // Finally at the end of my CellValueChanged event I added the
    // following code
    bsItemAdjust.EndEdit();
    dgvItems.NotifyCurrentCellDirty(true);
    dgvItems.EndEdit();
    dgvItems.NotifyCurrentCellDirty(false); 
}
```

I came across this solution on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16783511/how-to-finalize-a-new-row) and after some testing it seems to work perfectly.

Now the new row in my DataGridView is added to the bound DataTable at the end of the CellValueChanged event.

Comment: Good that you published the full story!

Comment: In my case just calling `bsItemAdjust.Endedit()` is what I needed to make my similar code work.  I was getting duplicate rows added, or the underlying datatable was not getting anything.